# Configure Firefox to allow Testing Cross Domain JSON Ajax calls from a file:// URL

Tags: android, ajax, firefox, cordova

Is it possible to set up Firefox to allow JSON/Ajax calls to my server
from a client html page loaded using the file:// protocol??

I am building a phonegap application which is loading web pages using
the file:// protocol and therefore XSS/XDS sandboxing rules don't
apply.  This is cool! Unfortunately, I can only get this to work from
my Android Emulator (see below for setup).  It does NOT work under
Firefox running on my Vista client machine.  This is disappointing
because I have grown used to using Firebug on the client to debug my
application.

FYI, The following setup works fine (but doesn't allow Firefox/Firebug
debugging)...

Server: Ubuntu running on Virtual Box, Eth0 in Bridged mode, node.js
returning a JSON messages)
Development (Host) Machine: Windows Vista running Eclipse with Android
SDK and Phonegap stuff loaded
Client: Application (.apk) deployed to the standard Android Emulator

Edit:  I eventually gave up on this and used JSONP :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you like Firefox but you could try Safari on Windows since it allows cross domain from file:// and it has good tools in the form of web inspector.

You could also try Sleight (https://github.com/alunny/sleight). which is a very simple proxy written in NodeJS specifically for PhoneGap.

Comment: the version of safari i downloaded had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [pre-Firefox 3, you could configure Firefox to allow cross-domain requests but not anymore](http://dirolf.com/2007/06/enabling-cross-domain-ajax-in-firefox.html).

I have two suggestions that you could explore:

1. If you have control over the server, you could set the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) header in your response from the server (temporarily) to `*` to allow *anyone* to get data from your URL (remember to remove that later!).
2. Use a proxy. It's pretty easy to set up Apache as proxy+reverse proxy for a limited number of URLs. This avoids the need to touch your server-side code and is probably the quicker, more reusable and less error prone of the two options.

   - http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies
   - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome. Its debug module is nearly Firebug in terms of quality and if you open it with

```
chrome.exe -allow-file-access-from-files
```

...it will allow cross-file access.